# How to map a prop in React, which is an array of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql

I'm trying to pass an array of objects to my MenuPage from the App.js. If there's no map, I can consolelog the `activities` prop I passed. But when I try to run the map I get an error and the console.log can no longer identify the `activities` prop, but instead I receive multiple console.logs of empty arrays.

Also, is this the correct way so that my `activities` render dynamically? I used to have the `activities` state on the MenuPage.js, but whenever I add a new activity, I'd have to refresh in order for the newly added activity to appear. Hence, I decided to try to move it in its parent file which is the App.js.

***error message when map***

> Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.

**Console log of `activities` prop if no map**

```
{getActivities: Array(5)}
    getActivities: Array(5)
        0: {id: "5e64abc6de157e027c1fc224", name: "Test1", location: "Test1", activityDate: "Test1", description: "Test1", …}
        1: {id: "5e69b103dd9e0b20f8636da9", name: "Test234", location: "Test2", activityDate: "Test2", description: "Test2", …}
        2: {id: "5e6a744eca11a3355cdde03b", name: "test3", location: "test3", activityDate: "test3", description: "test3", …}
        3: {id: "5e6a74c9be805e042057b3b1", name: "test4", location: "test4", activityDate: "test4", description: "test4", …}
        4: {id: "5e6a74e4be805e042057b3b2", name: "test5", location: "test5", activityDate: "test5", description: "test5", …}
        length: 5
__proto__: Array(0)
```

**MenuPage.js**

```
const MenuPage = ({activities}) => {
    const [activity, setActivity] = useState([])

    console.log(activities)

    setActivity(activities.map( (activity) => <ActivityItem activity={activity} />))
```

**App.js**

```
const App = () => {
    const [activities, setActivities] = useState([])

    useEffect( () => {
        GQLClient({}).request(Query.getActivities, null).then( ({getActivities}) => {
            setActivities({getActivities})
        })
    }, [])

    const Load = (props, page) => {
        if (user.token === null) return <Redirect to="/login" />

        if (page === 'LogoutPage') {
            unsetUser()
            return <Redirect to="/login" />
        }

        switch (page) {
            case 'MenuPage': return <MenuPage activities={activities} />

            default:
        }
    }

    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
            <AppNavbar />
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path='/register' component={ RegisterPage } />
                <Route exact path='/login' component={ LoginPage } />
                <Route exact path='/' render={ (props) => Load(props, 'MenuPage') } />
            </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
  )
}
```

Comment: Why is MenuPage.js storing the activities in a state called activity? If you just want to render it then you `return <>{activities.map(a=>ActivityItem activity={a} key={a.id}/>}</>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are seeing the infinite renders as you are using `setState` is inside a component.

`setActivity(activities.map( (activity) => <ActivityItem activity={activity} />))`

When it encounters it it re renders the component, at which time it will run into the above state again on the next render.

Just remove it as you already have access to `activities` in the context of the component and just return from the component instead.

```
return activities.map( (activity) => <ActivityItem activity={activity} />)
```

**naked useStates always causes infinite renders**

Also it always makes sense to move the data source as close as possible as the `App.js` page does not really use it but rather passes it down to the child components.

You can move the `useEffect` to `MenuPage` after fixing the return statement and it should work as expected.

**MenuPage.js**

```
const MenuPage = ({activities}) => {
    const [activities, setActivities] = useState([])

    // This only causes a re render once when the component is mounted
    // as the dependency list is empty
    useEffect( () => {
        GQLClient({})
           .request(Query.getActivities, null)
           .then( ({getActivities}) => {
              setActivities({getActivities});
         })
    }, [])

    console.log(activities)

    return (
       activities.map( (activity) => <ActivityItem key={activity.id} activity={activity} />
    );
}
```

Comment: Good anser, you forgot `<ActivityItem activity={activity} key={activity.id}/>` though

Comment: My bad. Updated it. Thanks !

Comment: Thank you so much! Do you know why whenever I add a new item, I need to refresh the MenuPage before the newly added item appears?

Comment: You are welcome. That is because you might not be updating `activities` with the new item that was added.

Answer (score 1):

Unless some code is missing, `MenuPage` components cannot work. You have to return a React Node (ie: a JSX element), but you're not returning anything.

The errore you're getting is because you call `setActivity()` at every render, triggering a re-render every time (until React stops it with an error).